# Clearing The Checked li Items When Checked From Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have an array in localstorage that I am printing to the browser.

I made a jsfiddle to show my code structure [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lasgw7qp/)

I am trying to make a whole div clickable. In other words the whole div changes colors when clicked but I am hiding the actual checkbox.

Then I added a button which clears all the checked items from the array in localstorage.

After doing this 
It is almost working. It only reloads the keywords in the array if there are none left. So if it is only showing one. Then I check it, it will reload. But if there is two and I check it, it will clear the one that I clicked. Any idea why its always keeping one?

I am loading the keywords like this,

```
$('#keyWords').prepend('<li class="list-group-item" data-style="button"><input id="'+localArray[i]+'" class="check" name="check" type="checkbox"><label for="'+localArray[i]+'">'+localArray[i]+'</label></li>');
```

Then I am trying to remove the keywords like this,

```
// Allows user to remove keywords from the locaStorage
$('#clearChecked').click(function() {
  currentArray = [];
  $('.check').each(function() {
    var $curr = $(this);
    if (!$curr.is(':checked')) {
      var value = $curr.parent().text();
      currentArray.push(value);
      localStorage.setItem('keyWords', JSON.stringify(currentArray));
      loadKeyWords();
    } else {
      $curr.parent().remove();
    }
  });
```

By removing the checkbox with css is it not becoming active when the li is clicked? That is the only reason I can think of why this is not working... It was working before I made the whole div clickable.

Just in case here is the css I added.

```
label {
display:block;
line-height:40px;
height:40px;
width: 520px;
border-radius:40px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
margin-top:10px;
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
color:gray;
text-align:center;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
display: none;
}

input:checked + label {
color: #F00;
}

input:checked + label:before {
content: "\2713";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the fiddle provided didn't work because you didn't provide us a function loadKeyWords().

That being said, it looks like you're rewriting the entire list into storage inside of the each loop. This doesn't make sense because you want to load all of the options into the array, and then set the value after the loop once.

I'm not sure if that will help you get closer to finding the real root of the problem.

Comment: ya but the function loadKeywords loads the keywords that are in the local storage. So if the clear function was working then the keywords would not be reloaded anyways. I need to know why the keywords are not being removed. The clear function I provided adds all the keywords which are not checked an creates a new array with them. Some how the way I have it is not check marking the keyword when I select it so its not being removed. .

Comment: I figured it out. It is working. It only reloads the keywords in the array if there are none left. So if it is only showing one. Then I check it it will reload. But if there is two and i check it will clear the one that I clicked. Any idea why its always keeping one?

Comment: localStorage.setItem('keyWords', JSON.stringify(currentArray));

is inside of your .each() loop. so it overwrites it every iteration. Maybe? - If I had everything I needed to run it in a fiddle I could debug and say for sure.